# Angular JS -How to mention module dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

I just started to learn Angular JS Framework and I get this extremely weird doubt:)

After you name a module for instance  - `moduleName`
And this `moduleName` depends on      - `anotherModule`

Then, you write:

```
   var myCoolApp = angular.module('moduleName', ['anotherModule']);
```

But if `anotherModule` depends on `anotherAwesomeModule`, should I write:

```
   var myCoolApp = angular.module('moduleName', ['anotherModule', 'anotherAwesomeModule'])
```

Or is it going to take care of itself ?? I am Wondering ..

Comment: Sorry if my question is Extreeeeeeeeemely Stupid . I just started to learn Angular JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
angular.module('anotherModule', ['anotherAwesomeModule']);
angular.module('moduleName', ['anotherModule']);
```

will work.

And it is a good thing to do

```
angular.module('anotherModule', ['anotherAwesomeModule']);
angular.module('moduleName', ['anotherModule', 'anotherAwesomeModule']);
```

if `moduleName` itself depends on `anotherAwesomeModule`. Even if `anotherModule` stops to depend on it, the code still works as intended.